# python, dataframe replace S(south) N(north) to - and +

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace the string in the data frame with "+" "-", so I can scatter plot on the map. 
I know only basic about the python and I am using Anaconda navigator, 
This is what I tried and I have error, can you help me? [dataframe of longitude and latitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyu1d.png)

and

```
for i in range(1):
    if(location.iloc[i][2]=='N'):
        df.iloc[i]=float("+" + location.iloc[i][0:2])

    for i in range(1):
        if(location.iloc[i][2]=='N'):
            df.iloc[i]=float("+" + location.iloc[i][0:2])
        else if(location.iloc[i][2]== 'S'):
            df.iloc[i]=float("-" + location.iloc[i][0:2])

    else if(location.iloc[i][2]== 'S'):
        df.iloc[i]=float("-" + location.iloc[i][0:2])
```

I tried, and I got error, what I supposed to have is ex)`4.5N==> +4.5`

Comment: `else if` is a syntax error.  Please edit your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* use manual loops for functions which can be easily vectorised.

This is one solution via `pd.Series.str` accessor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['4.5N', '3.5S', '1.0N', '2.5S', '1.5S']})

print(df['col'].dtype)
# object

df['col'] = np.where(df['col'].str[-1] == 'N',
                     df['col'].str[:-1].astype(float),
                     -df['col'].str[:-1].astype(float))

print(df['col'].dtype)
# float64

print(df['col'])
# 0    4.5
# 1   -3.5
# 2    1.0
# 3   -2.5
# 4   -1.5
# Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax error `else if`, correct: `elif`
2. Both for loop are useless, they perform a single iteration and set i to 0, you can replace it with `i = 0` or better yet, directly use the value 0 as index, or consider the following function to perform your conversion:

   ```
   def convert_location(location):
       direction = location[-1] # index -1 gives the last character
       location_val = location[:-1]
       conversion_dict = {
           'N': '+',
           'S': '-'
       }
       result_str = '%s%s' % (conversion_dict.get(direction), location_val)
   ```